# Why elastic load balancer not attaching EC2 instance in Amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I added EC2 instance to 'Elastic Load Balancer' by clicking edit instances button in AWS management console, it gives me status message 'Out Of Service'. Is there is any dependencies to attach instance to load balancer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution, that is

Health check was not configured properly, it gives 302(redirect error).

I reconfigured health check again with proper ping path...
It's working fine..

Answer (score 1):

Check instance security group inbound rules, should be added ELB security group

Comment: Can you give me guidance how can I add that ??
I checked my security group have only SSH and HTTP , how can I add ELB ?

Comment: 1. Select your security group on Security Groups Page
2. Click "Edit"
3. Click "Add Rule"
4. Select Type
5. Source section select "Custom IP"
6. Write your ELB name and select your ELB security group
7. Click "Save"

Comment: 4. select Type -> what I need to select in the list and what about port number ?

Comment: It's changable. If your app serve 80, you can select HTTP.